# Print WPF ItemsControl Across Multiple Pages

Tags: wpf, printing, itemscontrol

I've got an `ItemsCollection` hosted inside a `ScrollViewer` that is large enough to span multiple pages when printed. I've so far managed to print a single page using `PrintVisual(itemsControl)` but from what I've read, I need to approach printing a single control accross multiple pages differently. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is clipping.

You have to calculate the clip size and clip the control's image into required amount of portions according to your page size and maintain those clip images in a list and send them to your preint logic.

**Procedure:**
You need to conver the visual into RenderTargetBitmap with required encoding.

Then, by using CroppedBitmap, you can clip the bitmap image into required dimension. Then, maintain those clips in a `List<Image>` like so. Then, iterate and print them using your printing logic. If you want a sample I'll try to provide. I think is very old post. Hopefully, this would be helpful for some one in future.

Answer (score 0):

Check this implementation of [WPF Reports](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex. I used these in one of my app which exactly does this. If you want to know how.. just look into the code.